# Custom WPF control with Unity failing to resolve

Tags: wpf, unity-container, prism

```
public class RichTextBoxExtended : RichTextBox
{
    static RichTextBoxExtended()
    {
        //DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(RichTextBoxExtended), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(RichTextBoxExtended)));
    }

    public byte[] Text
    {
        get { return (byte[])GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(byte[]), typeof(RichTextBoxExtended), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(TextChangedCallback)));

    private static void TextChangedCallback(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RichTextBoxExtended richTextBoxExtended = obj as RichTextBoxExtended;
        richTextBoxExtended.ChangeText(e);
    }

    private void ChangeText(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //clear out any formatting properties
        TextRange range = new TextRange(base.Document.ContentStart, base.Document.ContentEnd);
        range.ClearAllProperties();

        //load bytes into stream, load stream into range
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(e.NewValue as byte[]);
        range.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
    }
}
```

Above is the custom control...

XAML implementing custom control...

```
<Grid>
    <controls:RichTextBoxExtended x:Name="Document" Text="{Binding Path=File}">
    </controls:RichTextBoxExtended>
</Grid>
```

Associated VM...

```
public class FileViewerViewModel : AViewModel
{
    private byte[] _file = null;

    public FileViewerViewModel(ILoggerFacade logger)
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the <seealso cref="DataFormats.Rtf"/> file representation as a <seealso cref="byte[]"/>
    /// </summary>
    public byte[] File
    {
        get 
        {
            return _file;
        }
        set 
        {
            _file = value;
            RaiseChanged(() => this.File);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally..if I call...

```
FileViewerView view = _container.Resolve<FileViewerView>();
```

It fails.

```
Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "cyos.infrastructure.Views.FileViewerView", name = "". Exception message is: The current build operation (build key Build Key[cyos.infrastructure.Views.FileViewerView, null]) failed: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (Strategy type BuildPlanStrategy, index 3)
```

If I remove the binding from within the XAML...

```
<Grid> 
    <controls:RichTextBoxExtended x:Name="Document">
    </controls:RichTextBoxExtended>
</Grid>
```

Everything works without a hitch...no problems at all...ideas?

EDIT:

Switched to creating a new instance, bypassing Unity. Issue is still in the same place, exception at construction of FileViewerView at InitializeComponent() with "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ProvideValueFromMarkupExtension(MarkupExtension markupExtension, Object obj, Object member)
   at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadPropertyArrayEndRecord()
   at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadRecord(BamlRecord bamlRecord)
   at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.Read(Boolean singleRecord)
   at System.Windows.Markup.TreeBuilderBamlTranslator.ParseFragment()
   at System.Windows.Markup.TreeBuilder.Parse()
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at cyos.infrastructure.Views.FileViewerView.InitializeComponent() in c:\Documents and Settings\amciver\My Documents\dev\cyos\cyos\cyos.infrastructure\Views\FileViewerView.xaml:line 1
   at cyos.infrastructure.Views.FileViewerView..ctor(FileViewerViewModel viewModel) in  now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the problem with array, but List<byte> works.

Comment: It did indeed work...a bit frustrated by that...only thing I can think is that a List = class byte = struct...